# \includegraphics with height of multiple lines

Tags: vertical-alignment

As a vertical spacer between paragraphs in a book (see picture), I want to insert a small image that has a height of several lines (some definable number) and a definable amount of vertical space before and after it. The image should not mess with the rest of the vertical text alignment on that page. That is, the bottom should be flush and agree with preceding and succeeding pages.

Of course I could manually figure out the correct spacings by trial and error and add corresponding vertical spaces to get the bottom flush, but this is font/documentclass dependent. Also, problems arise when the image occurs at either the top or the bottom of the page, or when the preceding paragraph is just a few words long (see second image).

[image: Example of image spacer, separating two paragraphs.]

[image: Wrong spacing when preceding paragraph is very short or when the image is place at top of page.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the height of the included image as a multiple of `\baselineskip`.

```
\newcommand\vspacer
  {\par
     {\centering
      \raisebox{-0.2\baselineskip}%
        {\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image}%
        }%
      \par
     }%
  }
```

According to the discussion in the comments, the lines of a page should get aligned with the corresponding lines of the other pages. Therefore one has to take care that space like `\parskip` and `\lineskip` do not stretch or shrink. This can be obtained by issuing the command `\raggedbottom` and by removing the stretch.

```
\raggedbottom
\lineskip0pt
\parskip0pt
```

In the example below I load the package `showframe` to mark the border of the text area.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand\vspacer
  {\par
     {\centering
      \raisebox{-0.2\baselineskip}%
        {\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image}%
        }%
      \par
     }%
  }
\raggedbottom
\lineskip0pt
\parskip0pt
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\vspacer
\Blindtext
\vspacer
\Blindtext
\vspacer
\Blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works fine. Also adding extra vspace before and/or after the spacer seems to be no problem. However, for some reason your method does not work if one uses the "oneside" option, for example, with \documentclass[12pt,d5paper,oneside]{scrbook}. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Muk If I change the first line of my sample document to `\documentclass[12pt,d5paper,oneside]{scrbook}`, then I only get the warning that the option `d5paper` hasn't been used, but otherwise the document stays the same (except for the margins). There must be something else in your document that causes the problem.

Comment: I used your exact same code, but \flushbottom was missing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After all, it seems your solutions does not work all the time. If I add in your example more spacers and blindtext (\Blindtext
\vspacer), say eight of them, you can see the alignment problems, especially if the spacer image appears at the top of the page.

Comment: @Muk What exactly do understand by alignment problem? If `\flushbottom` is activated (which is the default for the book class), then TeX will fill the complete page (provided you don't prevent it by too little stretchable space). Add the line `\usepackage{showframe}` to your preamble and check yourself. Or do you want to have *all* lines of a page aligned with the corresponding lines of all the other pages?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the alignment of all lines of both pages with respect to one another. I don't want the lines to be spread. That's why I asked how to insert a spacer image that has exactly the height of several lines. This image (with some definable vertical white space before and after it) should work whether it's placed in the middle of the page or at the top/bottom. Werner's suggestion of adding "plus xxx minus xxx" glue works to some degree, but I still get page alignment issues with the spacer at the top/bottom of the page. Maybe because of something called /topskip.

Comment: @Muk I have adapted my answer. If you observe further anomalities regarding alignment, please ask a new question. Don't forget to post the actual code that you use, in particular the documentclass and any other settings that might affect spacing.

Comment: This works fine. The last thing missing is some vertical white space before and after the image spacer. For a spacer of height of 2\baselineskip, I would like to have 0.5\baselineskip space before and after it, so it adds up to 3\baselineskip. The problem is that one of the 0.5\baselineskip is ignored when the image spacer is placed at the top or bottom of the page. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Muk Add `\vspace*{0.5\baseline}` in front of `\par` before and after the image. The star ensures that the space is not swallowed.

Comment: This does not work if the spacer image occurs at the top of a new page. In fact, the image will now never appear at the very top of the page, but LaTeX rather places the last line of the previous page before the image on the new page. Apparently, this has to do with the implementation of \vspace*. Following http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296278/vertical-space-different-at-top-of-first-page somehow solves that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would add some glue to the space before and after the spacer. This would allow them to stretch/shrink as needed in order to maintain a `\flushbottom`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\newcommand{\insertseparator}{%
  \par
  \vspace{.2\baselineskip plus .2\baselineskip minus .2\baselineskip}% Space above
  \noindent
  \makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image}}%
  \par
  \vspace{.2\baselineskip plus .2\baselineskip minus .2\baselineskip}% Space below
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\insertseparator

\lipsum[2-14]

\insertseparator

\lipsum[15-29]

\insertseparator

\lipsum[30-45]

\insertseparator

\lipsum[46-50]

\end{document}
```

You may have to play around with suitable values for `plus` and/or `minus`. I've just used part of a `\baselineskip`.